# ModelBinder is not invoked

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, autofac, modelbinders

Per [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228144/bind-action-1-2-3-to-listint), I implemented a model binder that maps `/api/v1/widgets/1,2,3` to

```
// WidgetsController.cs: 
public ActionResult Show(IEnumerable<int> idArgs)
{

}
```

This was working for a while, but now it is not any longer. **My ModelBinder is not even being invoked at all.** When my action is invoked, `idArgs` has a value of the empty list, even if I set its default value to `null` in the route, which suggests to me that the default model binder thinks it's getting a value from somewhere. The only change I've made since last week when it was working is that previously, I had called my action `ShowMany.`  Since then, I renamed it to `Show`. Can anyone help me figure out why my ModelBinder is not being invoked?

In global.asax.cs, I have

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());

    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IEnumerable<int>), new IEnumerableOfIntCSVModelBinder());
}
```

And the route looks like this (I have verified that this route is being used):

```
context.MapRoute(
    "show",
    "api/{controller}/{idArgs}",
    new { action = "show" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET"), idArgs = @"^(\d+,)+\d+,?$" }
);
```

---

**Edit:** I've tried messing messing with the routes some more, as well as commenting out the `JsonValueProvider`, and I'm still getting an empty array. In my controller, I can do

```
var ids = RouteData.Values["idArgs"];
```

and get the string "1,2,3". If only the framework would pass this to my ModelBinder, my ModelBinder would turn it into the `IEnumerable`.

I am using AutoFac. Is it possible that AutoFac is injecting an empty array into my controller method? I haven't had problems like this in other places (and we use AutoFac everywhere in this project.)

---

**Edit2**: I also tried decorating both the `idArgs` action parameter, and the controller with `[ModelBinder(typeof(IEnumerableOfIntCSVModelBinder))]`, but this had no effect.

Comment: If you change the action back to ShowMany, does that make it work again?

Comment: I just double-checked, and it does not.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer but if it was working before but now it's not, and you're using source control effectively, maybe you can pinpoint the commit where the code went from working to not.

Comment: Hi- any chance you can 'bisect' your source control history to find the commit where this broke? Probably the quickest answer given the number of variables.

Comment: Yeah, not a bad idea gentleman. Unfortunately, this project needs to get done more than it needs to use a suitable model binder, so I'm likely to just parse the strings in the controller.

Comment: Can you post the code for `IEnumerableOfIntCSVModelBinder` class?

Comment: Alternatively, trying setting a breakpoint in this class and stepping through. Or if you never hit the breakpoint then you know it's not getting in there.

Comment: I set a breakpoint in the `BindModel` method of the model binder (I belive that's what it's called, I don't have the source here), and it's not getting there. I also set a breakpoint in the constructor of the model binder, and it *is* getting there.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have a `JsonValueProviderFactory` added in your `Application_Start`. Maybe there is something in the implementation of this factory that prevents the model binder from being hit?

Also the url you have shown `/api/v1/widgets/1,2,3` has no relation to the route definition that you have `"restapi/{controller}/{idArgs}"`.

Comment: Yeah, the JsonValueProvider does seem like a possible candidate... it was there last week as well, but there might be something different about the request. The route mismatch is just an artifact of copy-pasting from a previous example, they match in reality.

Comment: I commented out the JsonValueProvider, but the modelbinder is still not invoked... no idea what's going on here, I guess I'm going to have to give up on it.

Comment: @notJim, if you have the possibility to send me your project I can take a look at what's wrong with it (no promise for time though).

Comment: That's very generous of you, but I'm afraid I'm unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try moving your route to be the first one registered? I just tried coding this up and had an issue where my route wasn't firing until I moved it's registration above the default route registration. Routes appear to be run in the order they are registered, so if you have a more specific registration after and more general registration, it may not fire.

In this example, the second route never gets called:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Ids",
    "{controller}/{action}/{ids}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", ids = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { ids = @"^(\d+,)+\d+,?$" });
```

But if you reverse their order, then "Ids" gets called.