# Custom model binder not called when type is nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, custom-model-binder

I have a custom struct called `TimeOfDay` which is used in a view model like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public TimeOfDay TimeOfDay { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a custom model binder called `TimeOfDayModelBinder` and registered it in Global.asax.cs like this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TimeOfDay), new TimeOfDayModelBinder());
```

And everything works great. However, if I change my view model to this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public TimeOfDay? TimeOfDay { get; set; } // Now nullable!
}
```

My custom model binder is no longer called. I know that the property is no longer a type of TimeOfDay, but a Nullable which is different. So does this mean I should add my custom model binder twice in Global.asax.cs like this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TimeOfDay), new TimeOfDayModelBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TimeOfDay?), new TimeOfDayModelBinder());
```

It works, but there's just something I don't like about it. Is this really necessary to handle my type as nullable, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. As far as I'm aware that's the standard way of doing it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having a kinda-similar (but not quite) issue. See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519548/).

Comment: @notJim I didn't really dig into any more, but the conclusion was that I needed to add the modelbinder twice. Once for the not-nullable and once for the nullable, as it's really two different types to the CLR.

Comment: By the way @LukeH, if you make an answer with your comment, I'll accept it as the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @LukeH's comment, it seems it is necessary. I guess that makes sense too, as `TimeOfDay` and `Nullable<TimeOfDay>` really is two different types in the CLR. So I guess I have to live with it. :-)

Answer (score 8):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but an alternative solution. There might be a better one...

In MVC3 you can create a IModelBinderProvider. An implementation would be something like this:

```
public class TimeOfDayModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType)
    {
          if(modelType == typeof(TimeOfDay) || modelType == typeof(TimeOfDay?))
            {
                 return  new TimeOfDayModelBinder();
            } 
           return null;
    }
}
```

You'd need to register it in your DependencyResolver/IOC container ***or*** do this (in the Global.asax - app start):

```
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new TimeOfDayModelBinderProvider());
```

Comment: +1 Interesting and nice to know. But in my case I think it would complicate matters more than it would simplify it. But thank you anyway. :-)